# Difference between transform and -webkit-transform in CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a snippet of code.

```
#nav a:hover {
transform:scale(1.3,1.3);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.3,1.3);
}
```

Here, both tranform:scale() and -webkit-transform:scale() are used.
But, It seems only transform:scale() can do the thing. Then, why is -webkit-transform:scale() used? Is there any difference between these two?

Comment: you no more need -webkit- on transform, simply remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webkit extension helps you target specific browsers. In this case, Google Chrome and Safari. Generally the standard `transform` (in this case) will be used however this just ensures all browsers will be compatible.

Comment: So, transform:scale(1.3,1.3) does scaling for all the browsers, right?

Comment: Transform is supported by all major browsers. See: https://caniuse.com/#search=transform. You would use the webkit prefix if you wanted to target Chrome and Safari specifically to make them do something else.

Comment: Too easy mate. Please feel free to mark it as the answer if you're happy with it.